# Mysql select query taking 100% of cpu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using select query to find records from the table. There are total 36751694 records in the table.

my select query is as below

```
"select * from authentication_codes where client_id=6 "
```

Above query taking 100% of cpu. i have indexed column `client_id` but still searching is very low. Also if i hit same query multiple times then i am getting error as "mysql server gone away". please help.

Thanks,

Comment: What type is `client_id` field and how many results are returned?

Comment: is the index used?  To check this add the keyword **explain** directly before the select statement.

Comment: @Vasfed - client_id is of integer type

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use the wrong database engine type. Try switching the table from one database engine to another.

Comment: my database engine type is innodb and i can't change its type to myissam because it doesn't provide support to transaction.